# Normal subgroups of automorphism group of relational structure

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, topological-groups, automorphism-groups, algebraic-systems

Let $S$ be the set of all finite permutations of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. they fix all but a finite set, and $A\subset S$ the set of all even permutations.

**Theorem.** The normal subgroups of $S_\infty$ are exactly the following four: $\{\mathrm{id}\}\subset A\subset S\subset S_\infty$ (see [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Normal_subgroups)).

Now, consider a model $M$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ be the group of  automorphisms of $M$. $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$ and every closed subgroup of $S_\infty$ equals $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$, for some model $M$.

> **My question**: Are there any (partial?) results generalizing the above  theorem to $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$? I.e. what are the normal subgroups of $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$, for various structures $M$? Equivalently, if $A$ is a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$, what are the normal subgroups of $A$?

Comment: I am curious to know where this Theorem is proved? (It's indeed well-known that $A$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup in $S$, but then?)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: I found it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Normal_subgroups

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: The reference on Wikipedia says "For more details see (Scott 1987, Ch. 11.3) or (Dixon & Mortimer 1996, Ch. 8.1)."

Comment: @DimaPasechnik See the addition to my answer.

Comment: There was some work attempted on an overgroup $G$ of $S$ , the subgroup of all "bounded" permutations - bounded in the sense that for each $\pi\in G$ satisfies $|k-\pi(k)|\leq b(\pi)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.  (everything what was published does not make much sense though :-))

Comment: Note that any countable discrete group $\Gamma$ occurs as closed subgroup of $S_\infty$ (through the left action), so a general result is hopeless without specific assumptions on $A$ (such as those in the MacPherson-Tent result in Igor Rivin's answer).

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer, but the closed subgroups of $S_\infty$ are classified in this paper by Bergman and Shelah:

*George M. Bergman and Saharon Shelah*, MR 2280223 [**Closed subgroups of the infinite symmetric group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00012-006-1959-z), *Algebra Universalis* **55** (2006), no. 2-3, 137--173.

To answer Dima Pasechnik's question in the comments, the Baer-Schreier-Ulam theorem follows from [the result proved by Manfred Droste and R Gobel, 1979.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6vz19qkn9f1xnq/drosteulam.pdf?dl=0)

**CLOSER TO AN ANSWER**
In their 2011 paper, MacPherson and Tent show (as conjectured in my comment) that these are often simple (the below is the beginning of the math review)

*Dugald Macpherson and Katrin Tent*, MR 2824528 [**Simplicity of some automorphism groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2011.05.021), *J. Algebra* **342** (2011), 40--52.:

> Let $M$ be a countably infinite first-order relational structure and let $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ be the automorphism group of $M$. The authors show that if $M$ is transitive, free, and homogeneous, and if $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is not the full symmetric group, then $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is simple. **Transitive** means that $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ acts transitively on $M$; **free** means the class of finite substructures of $M$ has the free amalgamation property; and **homogeneous** means that isomorphisms between finite substructures extend to $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$.

Comment: The paper that you cite characterizes the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $G1 ≈ G2$ if there exists a finite set $U\subset S_\infty$, such that $⟨G1∪U⟩=⟨G2∪U⟩$, where $G_1,G_2$ are closed subgroups of $S_\infty$. I fail to see how it relates to the question at hand.

Comment: There is certainly no classification of closed subgroups of $S_\infty$ in the usual sense (which suggest a full description), although there are important results about them (in the linked paper, they are split into 4 classes and some results are proved about these classes).

Comment: @YCor: Yes, but how this relates to finding the normal subgroups of a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$? I can not see any connection. I don't have access to the papaer, I just read the abstract. Does the classification give any information/hint about their normal subgroups?

Comment: I was answering the reply, not your comment. I have no claim as you suggest (on the other hand, you can easily find an arxiv version of the mentioned paper)

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos I clearly state that my answer is not an answer, but a pointer to some information that you might be able to use to try to arrive at an answer. My guess is that the groups you are interested in are close to simple (just like $S_\infty$ itself).

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos check out the edit.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer was edited

Here is a characterization I came up with:

**Definition**

- Let $G=Aut(M)$ (equiv. $G$ is a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$) and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. Define $x\sim_N y$ iff there exists an automorphism $g\in N$ such that $g.x=y$.
- $G$ respects $\sim_N$ if for all $x,y$, $$x\sim_N y\text{ iff } g.x\sim_N g.y$$

**Lemma** Let $M$ be a countable model, $G=Aut(M)$ and $N$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. The following are equivalent:

1. $N\vartriangleleft G$
2. $G$ respects $\sim_N$

*Proof*. Unfold the definitions
 \begin{align*}
   N & \vartriangleleft G \text{ iff }\\
%  \forall g\in G\; \forall n\in N\; \exists n'\in N,\; & g^{-1}ng=n' \text{ iff }\\
 \forall x\in M \forall g\in G\; \forall n\in N\; \exists n'\in N,\; & 
g^{-1}ng.x=n'.x \text{ iff }\\
  \forall x,y \in M \forall g\in G,\; & (\exists n\in N,\; y=g^{-1}ng.x) 
\leftrightarrow  (\exists n'\in N,\; y=n'.x) \text{ iff }\\
 \forall x,y \in M \forall g\in G,\; & (\exists n\in N,\; g.y=ng.x) 
\leftrightarrow  (\exists n'\in N,\;y=n'.x) \text{ iff }\\
  \forall x,y \in M \forall g\in G,\; & 
(g.x\sim_N g.y) \leftrightarrow  (x\sim_N y)
\end{align*}

*End of Proof.*

## Stabilizers

As a special case we prove that if $X$ is a $G$-invariant set, then point-wise stabilizer of $X$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**Definition** If $G$ is a group acting on $\mathbb{N}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $G_n$ denotes the stabilizer of $n$ in $G$. If $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $G_{X}$ denotes the pointwise-stabilizer of $X$.

**Lemma 1** For all $n,g$, $G_{g(n)}= g G_n g^{-1}$.

*Proof.* $f\in G_{g(n)}$ iff $f(g(n))=g(n)$ iff $g^{-1}(f(g(n)))=n$ iff $g^{-1}(f(g))\in G_n$ iff $f\in g G_n g^{-1}$. $\square$

**Corollary 2** For $X\subset\mathbb{N}$, $G_{g(X)}=g G_X g^{-1}$.

**Lemma 3** Let $G=Aut(M)$, for some $M$, and let $X$ be a $G$-invariant set. Then the pointwise-stabilizer of $X$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.

*Proof.*  Let $g\in G$. Since $X$ is G-invariant, $g(X)=X$. By Corollary 2, $G_X=G_{g(X)}=g G_X g^{-1}$, which proves the result. $\square$.

## Some Comments

- By Lemma 3, the number of normal subgroups of $G$ correlates with the number of $G$-orbits. We can construct an example of $G$ with $\aleph_0$-many normal subgroups, even with $2^{\aleph_0}$-many normal subgroups.
- In view of Lemma 3, $Aut(M)$ is a simple group, only if $Aut(M)$ acts trasitively on $M$, i.e. has only one orbit. So, it is necessary in the result mentioned by Igor Rivin that the $Aut(M)$ acts transitively on $M$.
- By a theorem of Dana Scott, every $Aut(M)$-orbit is defined by an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence (in the same vocabulary as $M$). If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $Aut(M)$, what can we say about the action of $N$ on $M$?